# Hierarchic structure Firestore and subcollections

Tags: mongodb, hierarchical-data, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a database with Cloud Firestore and having read the documentation about [hierarchic structure](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/data-model) I have found another solution to the one present in the documentation example.

I have a `collection` of categories, and each category can have subcategories. Whereas I could use the system provided in the Firestore documentation example such as `collection/document/subcollection/document...` I have found [another example](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/category-hierarchy/) for MongoDB where instead of having subcollections it uses nested data in a single document with parent-child relations as described in the image below

[image]

What approach is better if I want the `user` to be able to see all the subcategories so the user can categorize a certain `event`? By better I mean in terms of avoiding multiple connections to the DB (as this is what Firestore prices with).

Answer (score 3):

This document discusses nested data and its tradeoffs, ["Choose a Data Structure"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data). I'm not sure that the statement about multiple connections for pricing is correct. [Firestore charges for number of operations, storage, and network bandwidth.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#network)

If all users share a single categories list, you would be able to retrieve the entire list with one operation with your current structure. Note that there is a [1 MiB limit for document size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).