# FireStore Data Structuring Advice Please

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Please give me some advice on structuring data in FireStore we are going to have about 10K users for insurance using an App, logging products/tools covered and adding photos.

I have seen [Hierarchic structure Firestore and subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509846/hierarchic-structure-firestore-and-subcollections) , this helps but its not exactly what I wanted to ask.

Option 1: A single query/subscription
Option 2: More queries/subscription but less data exchange overall as requestes can be made for individual sections

Option 1....

```
ClientID
  ClientData
    Name
    Address
  Product
    ProductID
    PolicyNumber
    StartDate
    ExpriyDate
  Tools
    ProductID
    PolicyNumber
    StartDate
    ExpriyDate
    Photos
      0
      1
      2
  Claims
    ClaimID
    PolicyNumber
    Date
    Photos
```

Option 2....

```
ClientData
  Name
  Address
Product
  ClientID
    ProductID
    PolicyNumber
    StartDate
    ExpriyDate
Tools
  ClientID
    ProductID
    PolicyNumber
    StartDate
    ExpriyDate
    Photos
      0
      1
      2
Claims
  ClientID
    ClaimID
    PolicyNumber
    Date
    Photos
```

Comment: Have you looked at this video on [Firestore and NoSQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ)?

Comment: The structure is usually determined by the query patterns.  Can you explain a bit more of the use cases you expect?  If the client is going to need all (or most of the data) than Option 1 probably makes sense.  If you are concerned about about them not accessing data they don't need, Option 2 could be better.  It's hard to know the impact of multiple requests vs one large request since Firestore maintains an open connection.  Often the request overhead is much higher than a bit of extra data

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, it is by query as 99% of the time it will be "where client ID =" so I guess option 1 so I can just do

```
firebase.database().ref('db/' + this.user.uid'...
```